# ftp command mkdir newRootFolder causes error 553: “No such file in directory”

Tags: router, ftp, remote

My goal is to use my Router as ftp server to do backups on it.

I can connect by explorer as well as by `ftp`-command in cmd.exe.
In both cases I get the error

`553 Can't create "\mnt\TOSHIBAMK6465GSX\99_Backup": No such file or directory..`

when i try to create a new folder by `mkdir NewFolder` in the root. Creating a new folder inside already existing root-folders (by `mkdir ExistingFolder/NewFolder`) works pretty well.

So the Question is: How can I create a root-folder remotely by ftp?

---

Router Model: **o2 Box 6431**

Client-OS: **Windows 10**

Comment: Yes, in case of the access over the explorer. But in console i accessed just by ftp.

Comment: I do not understand. Are you sure you understood my question? Did you setup the mapping of the FTP folders (and mainly its root folder) **on the server** yourself?

Comment: I took a HDD (with 2 folders on it) and plugged it into my router. Then I was able to acces those folders. I did nothing else on the server.